# How to log with Syslog when a port is becoming “listening” or change state?

Tags: monitoring, syslog

Is it possible to log with Syslog when a new port is becoming listening in linux debian? how can i do that?

Moreover, is there a way to log to syslog results of `top` or `htop` commands?

Regards

Comment: Yes, you can install and configure auditd to log socket creation or connections.  Look for sites explaining how to create `audit.rules` for `auditd`.  Others will bash me for suggesting this; but yes, you can send top (in report mode) to `logger` to send that data to syslog.

Comment: Thank you Aaron. Could you please explain me why logger isn't a good way to log events?

Comment: Technically there is nothing wrong with that.  Some folks see that as a very cludgy ad-hoc method and would prefer rsyslog configured to read files generated by something daemonized.  That leads to many rabbit hole discussions.  It comes down to what works best for your situation.